# Using threading lock in ctypes callback function

Tags: python, multithreading, callback, ctypes

I want to use a ctypes dll from a twisted application.  Minimal example concocted here:

```
from ctypes import *
from threading import Lock

lock = Lock()

dll = windll.LoadLibrary('mydll.dll')

l = [1,2,3]

def callback():
    lock.acquire()
    l.pop()
    lock.release()
    return 0

C_CALLBACK = CFUNCTYPE(c_int)
c_callback = C_CALLBACK(callback)

# this is a non blocking function call starts a hardware task that fires a callback upon completion
dll.registerCallback(c_callback)

while(True):
    # in reality this block gets called from a twisted server application
    lock.acquire()
    l.append(l.pop() + 1)
    lock.release()
```

The dll has a function (`dll.registerCallback`) that takes in a ctypes callback function, starts a hardware event, and fires a callback when the hardware indicates the hardware task is complete.

From the API documentation:

> The callback function is called in a DAQmx thread.

Somewhere on the web they attempt to explain what a "DAQmx thread" is:

> ...your callback will be called and run in a DAQmx driver thread and will be run asynchronously (not in the same thread) in relation to your program.

The full documentation cound be found [here](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370471W-01/daqmxcfunc/daqmxregisterdoneevent/). I changed the function signature in my example for simplicity.

So I suppose we can safely assume that the dll is spawning a thread.

Will the locks I have in place ensure that the callback function does not attempt to access the list `l` when it's in the middle of the `pop` operation in the mainloop, and vice versa?  Or does this scheme only work when you use threads created using the `threading` library?  What is the recommended practice here?

Comment: I'm not certain that can ever work. I'm not sure that anything will initialise this thread so that it can work with Python.

Comment: I think eryksun's comment answers the question. Your lock is sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing that ctypes [`_CallPythonObject`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/70274d53c1dd/Modules/_ctypes/callbacks.c#l201) does is call [`PyGILState_Ensure()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/70274d53c1dd/Python/pystate.c#l583), which will call `PyThreadState_New` to create a new thread state if necessary. Beyond that it's vanilla Python threaded code, so your lock should work fine. It worked for me in the example below (Linux, Python 2.7.3):

```python
from ctypes import *
import threading

lock = threading.Lock()
lib = CDLL('./tmp.so')
callback_t = CFUNCTYPE(c_int)

def f():
  with lock:
    print threading.current_thread()
  return 21

callback = callback_t(f)
lib.registerCallback(callback)
```

```
>>> lock.acquire()
True
>>> t = threading.Thread(target=lib.event)
>>> t.start()
>>> lock.locked()
True
>>> lock.release()
>>> <_DummyThread(Dummy-2, started daemon -1230402704)>
res: 21
```

The `DummyThread` output is from printing the current thread in the callback. Threads created outside of Python get a 'dummy' name.

**tmp.c:**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

typedef int (*callback_t)(void);
callback_t callback = NULL;

void *doCallback(void *arg)
{
    int res = callback();
    printf("res: %d\n", res);
    pthread_exit(0);
}

int event(void)
{
    pthread_t callback_thread;
    pthread_create(&callback_thread, NULL, doCallback, NULL);
    pthread_join(callback_thread, NULL);
    return 0;
}

int registerCallback(callback_t foo)
{
    callback = foo;
    return 0;
}
```