# Completion routine for asynchronous call to ReadDirectoryChangesW

Tags: python, python-2.7, winapi, ctypes

I am trying to use `ReadDirectoryChangesW` (asynchronous mode with completion routine) from python.

Following the *Remarks* from [MS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465(v=vs.85).aspx) I learnt that an OVERLAPPED structure and a call back have to be provided.

The callback is described withing that documentation as:

```
VOID CALLBACK FileIOCompletionRoutine(
  _In_     DWORD dwErrorCode,
  _In_     DWORD dwNumberOfBytesTransfered,
  _Inout_  LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
);
```

So I instantiated the `ctypes` WINFUNCTYPE factory as:

```
RDCW_CALLBACK_F = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.wintypes.DWORD, ctypes.wintypes.DWORD, ctypes.POINTER(OVERLAPPED))
```

And tried to get access to `FileIOCompletionRoutine` call:

```
ReadDirectoryChangesW = ctypes.windll.kernel32.ReadDirectoryChangesW

ReadDirectoryChangesW.restype = ctypes.wintypes.BOOL
ReadDirectoryChangesW.errcheck = _errcheck_bool
ReadDirectoryChangesW.argtypes = (
    ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE,  # hDirectory
    LPVOID,  # lpBuffer
    ctypes.wintypes.DWORD,  # nBufferLength
    ctypes.wintypes.BOOL,  # bWatchSubtree
    ctypes.wintypes.DWORD,  # dwNotifyFilter
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.wintypes.DWORD),  # lpBytesReturned
    ctypes.POINTER(OVERLAPPED),  # lpOverlapped
    RDCW_CALLBACK_F  # FileIOCompletionRoutine # lpCompletionRoutine
)
```

Note that if I try to use `FileIOCompletionRoutine` as a synchronous call (passing `None` to its two last parameters) it works.

The problem comes when I try to pass a completion routine:

```
#Routine implementation
def dir_change_callback(dwErrorCode,dwNumberOfBytesTransfered,p):
    print("dir_change_callback!")

#Get WINFUNC from factory
call2pass = RDCW_CALLBACK_F(dir_change_callback)

try:
    event_buffer = ctypes.create_string_buffer(BUFFER_SIZE)
    nbytes = ctypes.wintypes.DWORD()
    overlapped_read_dir = OVERLAPPED()    
    ReadDirectoryChangesW(handle, ctypes.byref(event_buffer),
                          len(event_buffer), recursive,
                          WATCHDOG_FILE_NOTIFY_FLAGS,
                          ctypes.byref(nbytes), 
                          ctypes.byref(overlapped_read_dir), call2pass)
```

The call works and if I don't perform changes in the monitored directory during the program execution, it runs without crashes.
However, If a change occurs, the program crashes:

```
hand = get_directory_handle(os.path.abspath("/test/"))
read_directory_changes(hand, False)
time.sleep(10)
```

**Crash Report**

```
Nombre del evento de problema (Problem event name): APPCRASH
Nombre de la aplicación (Application Name):         python.exe
Nombre del módulo con errores (Module name):        ntdll.dll
Versión del módulo con errores (Module version):    6.1.7601.18247
Código de excepción (Exception code):               c0000005
Desplazamiento de excepción (Exception offset):     000337a2
Versión del sistema operativo (OS Version):         6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
```

I think the problem comes when WinApi tries to call the callback code so I suspect I am not building correcly the `WINFUNC` passed to the call.

On the other hand, I found at python [ctypes documentation site](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#callback-functions) the following warning:

> Note Make sure you keep references to CFUNCTYPE() objects as long as
>   they are used from C code. ctypes doesn’t, and if you don’t, they may
>   be garbage collected, crashing your program when a callback is made.

But I kept a global reference to the callable so, unless I am wrong, I don't think that is the problem.

Have you ever called `kernel32` windows calls passing callbacks implemented in python? Is the way I tried to do it right?

**EDIT**

I just figured out what was generating the crash: `event_buffer` wasn't global and it was being collected before the callback started.
Although making it global fixed the crash, the message `"dir_change_callback!"` is not being printed in the process terminal. I tried to create a new file from the callback and write some message to it but still the result was thr same: **It is like the callback is not being executed**. This is rather strange since the crash described above should be associated with the callback execution.

`ctypes` documentation states:

> Also, note that if the callback function is called in a thread created
>   outside of Python’s control (e.g. by the foreign code that calls the
>   callback), ctypes creates a new dummy Python thread on every
>   invocation. This behavior is correct for most purposes, but it means
>   that values stored with threading.local will not survive across
>   different callbacks, even when those calls are made from the same C
>   thread.

Being a complete newbie to `ctypes`, I understand this *dummy thread* is a thread of the process which performed the system call and, maybe, this process gets terminated before the call is executed. 
This question [Using threading lock in ctypes callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15952086/using-threading-lock-in-ctypes-callback-function) seems to support that idea. I tried to reproduce that question lock-scheme within my code but the lock remains unlocked just as the version trying to print: The callback doesn't seem to execute:

```
lck = threading.Lock()
lck.acquire()

def dir_change_callback(dwErrorCode,dwNumberOfBytesTransfered,p):
    lck.release()
```

Comment: Did you ever get this working?